# Mongoose Return One Object from Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose and I have this data in my mongodb :

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f13e1edf7c56a896987c191"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "email" : "klinikkoding@gmail.com",
    "firstName" : "Klinik",
    "lastName" : "Koding",
    "resetToken" : null,
    "workspaces" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f13e124f7c56a896987c18e"),
            "code" : "kk",
            "name" : "Klinik Koding",
            "_roleId" : ObjectId("5f13de3eb33fa33ce2a3b0dd")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "invited",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f13e13ff7c56a896987c190"),
            "code" : "rm",
            "name" : "The Manage",
            "_roleId" : ObjectId("5f13de3eb33fa33ce2a3b0dd")
        }
    ],
```

How can I return only one workspace? The output that I need is like this:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f13e1edf7c56a896987c191"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "email" : "klinikkoding@gmail.com",
    "firstName" : "Klinik",
    "lastName" : "Koding",
    "resetToken" : null,
    "workspaces" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f13e124f7c56a896987c18e"),
            "code" : "kk",
            "name" : "Klinik Koding",
            "_roleId" : ObjectId("5f13de3eb33fa33ce2a3b0dd")
        }, 
    ],
```

Anyone can help me with this query?

Comment: Try using the [$(projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
async function retrieve(){
    // You can retrieve it by any field. I used email because it is unique.
    let data=await yourModelName.findOne({email:"klinikkoding@gmail.com"}) 
    data.workspaces.splice(1,1)
    console.log("your final result",data)
 }

retrieve()
```